# Laravel File import in database

Tags: php, laravel

I have properly followed all these steps which are mentioned in this link "http://www.expertphp.in/article/laravel-5-maatwebsite-import-excel-into-db-and-export-data-into-csv-and-excel"

But when i run this url in my browser "http://localhost:8000/route66/import-export-csv-excel" i got the below error

> "Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found."

its my routes.php:

```
Route::get('import-export-csv-excel',array('as'=>'excel.import','uses'=>'FileController@importExportExcelORCSV'));
Route::post('import-csv-excel',array('as'=>'import-csv-excel','uses'=>'FileController@importFileIntoDB'));
Route::get('download-excel-file/{type}', array('as'=>'excel-file','uses'=>'FileController@downloadExcelFile'));
```

Comment: Is your web server running and properly configured? Do other routes work? Do other pages on your web server work? Is `/route66/` a name of the project on your webserver or should it be included in the URL part of the Route command?

Comment: Based on your route, URL should be `http://localhost:8000/import-export-csv-excel`

Comment: yes route66 is a project name

Comment: @MilanChheda i have run this same url its still showing that error please guide thanks

Comment: Try cloning and standing up this to see if the issue replicates: https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-excel-example

Comment: Heres those routes: https://github.com/jeremykenedy/laravel-excel-example/blob/master/routes/web.php

Comment: I was able to get it going with that example in the past.

Comment: show us whats on `importExportExcelORCSV` function

Comment: Hope you have started the local server by running `php artisan serve`